# getServerSideProps data rendering

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

i am new to next js and firebase so i wanna pass an id(firebase  auth ) to getServerSideProps but i cnat get the data i want i am using js cookie to store the id and notrhing is working i use a lot of ways but nothing seems to work  and for the cookie i stor it in the the other component and if i consol log it in the placard component i still get it so the uid is exist

here is my code :

this placard component :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db, auth } from "../config/firebase";    
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import retrieveProjects from "../lib/retrieveProjects";
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
  onSnapshot
} from "firebase/firestore";
export default function Placard({ProjList}) {
console.log(Cookies.get('uid'));
return (
    <div className="container mx-auto">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Placard</h1>
    
          <table className="table-auto">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th className="px-4 py-2">Project ID</th>
                <th className="px-4 py-2">Apartment ID</th>
                <th className="px-4 py-2">Door ID</th>
                <th className="px-4 py-2">Width</th>
                <th className="px-4 py-2">Height</th>
                <th className="px-4 py-2">Thickness</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
  {ProjList?.map((row) => (
    <tr key={Math.random()}>
      <td className="border px-4 py-2">{row.projectId}</td>
      <td className="border px-4 py-2">{row.apartmentId}</td>
      <td className="border px-4 py-2">{row.doorId}</td>
      <td className="border px-4 py-2">{row.width}</td>
      <td className="border px-4 py-2">{row.height}</td>
      <td className="border px-4 py-2">{row.thickness}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
          </table>
       
    </div>
  );
}
export async function getServerSideProps() {

  const uid = Cookies.get('uid')
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res =retrieveProjects(uid)
  const dataList = await res.json();
 
  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { 
    ProjList:dataList,
   }, };
}

and this the method i call :

import { db, auth } from "../config/firebase";
import {
    collection,
    getDocs,
    onSnapshot
  } from "firebase/firestore";
this my func
export default function retrieveProjects(userId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        // console.log(Cookies.get('uid'));
        // Create a reference to the user's projects collection
        const projectsCollectionRef = collection(db, "users", userId, "projects");
  
        // Listen for changes to the projects collection
        onSnapshot(projectsCollectionRef, (querySnapshot) => {
          const data = [];
          const promises = []; // Array to store promises for each data retrieval
  
          querySnapshot.forEach((projectDoc) => {
            const apartmentsCollectionRef = collection(
              projectDoc.ref,
              "apartments"
            );
  
            const apartmentPromise = getDocs(apartmentsCollectionRef).then(
              (apartmentQuerySnapshot) => {
                const apartmentPromises = []; // Array to store promises for each apartment retrieval
  
                apartmentQuerySnapshot.forEach((apartmentDoc) => {
                  const doorsCollectionRef = collection(apartmentDoc.ref, "Doors");
  
                  const doorsPromise = getDocs(doorsCollectionRef).then(
                    (doorQuerySnapshot) => {
                      const doorsData = [];
  
                      doorQuerySnapshot.forEach((doorDoc) => {
                        const dataRow = {
                          projectId: projectDoc.id,
                          apartmentId: apartmentDoc.id,
                          doorId: doorDoc.id,
                          width: doorDoc.data().porte_width,
                          height: doorDoc.data().porte_height,
                          thickness: doorDoc.data().porte_thickness,
                        };
                        doorsData.push(dataRow);
                      });
  
                      data.push(...doorsData);
                    }
                  );
  
                  apartmentPromises.push(doorsPromise);
                });
  
                return Promise.all(apartmentPromises);
              }
            );
  
            promises.push(apartmentPromise);
          });
  
          Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
            console.log("Data retrieved successfully:", data);
            resolve(data); // Resolve the promise with the retrieved data
          });
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error retrieving data:", error);
        reject(error); // Reject the promise if there is an error
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`js-cookies` is a client library (browser only) so it will not work on a server (inside `getServerSideProps` call)

you will have to obtain the cookie from a request passed to `getServerSideProps` e.g.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const cookies = context.req.cookies
  ...
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-server-side-props#context-parameter

Comment: so when i go to aplication in inspicte i find my cookie with the name of uid and it have the id of the user how can get acces to that cookie and use it export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const{req}=context;
  const cookies = req.headers.cookie;
  const tableData = await retrieveProjects(cookies);

  return {
    props: {
      tableData,
    },
  };
} didnt work$

Comment: in your case it would be `const uid = context.req.cookies.uid`